# Trying to check whether value has been inputted in the text boxes

Tags: c#, validation

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code here, i am trying to do data validation by checking if the user has inputted any values in the text box, but when i run the code it will carry on saving the card regardless if there are values entered or not inside the text boxes.

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nameChosenOnCard  = textBoxName.Text;
    numOfCard = textBoxCardNum.Text;
    cardStartDate = textBoxStartMonth.Text + "/" + textBoxStartYear.Text;
    cardEndDate = textBoxEndmonth.Text + "/" + textBoxEndYear.Text;
    nameDetailsOnCard = textBoxNameOnCard.Text;
    cardCVC= textBoxCVC.Text;

    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxName.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxCardNum.Text) &&
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxStartMonth.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxStartYear.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxEndmonth.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxEndYear.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxNameOnCard.Text) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxCVC.Text))
    {
        buttonSave.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        buttonSave.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where are your textboxes located?

Comment: You should use parentheses around your conditions

Comment: @TimSchmelter yeah ive done that initially but it gives me an error

Comment: @AndreiSolero what do you mean?

Comment: It's *too late* disabling button `buttonSave.Enabled = false` when result *has been assigned*: `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;`

Comment: `&&` is binding more than `||`. Therefore your check is equivalent to (simplyfied): `Name || (CardNum && StartMonth) || Year || Endmonth || EndYear || NameOnCard || CVC`.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko so the dialogResult.OK; should be put inside the else statement?

Comment: You are setting `buttonSave.Enabled` when `buttonSave` has already been clicked! You must set `buttonSave.Enabled` in the Validated or PropertyChanged events of all the textboxes.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes can you elaborate on that just a bit? i don't know much about c#

Comment: See: [Learn C#](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/csharp) and also [learn c# winforms](https://www.google.com/search?q=learn+c%23+winforms).

Comment: @Sulekha: 1. `buttonSave.Enabled` is of no use here. 2. `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` should be in the `else`. 3. I suggest to let user know *which* control in invalid (put a keyboard focus on it) and what's going on (message box)

Answer (score 2):

You *save* first

```
 DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

then *validate* and trying to *act*:

```
if (...)
{
    buttonSave.Enabled = false;
}
```

Let's extract a method for validation:

```
// Let's be more friendly and show to user which control has invalid value
private Control InvalidControl() {
  //TODO: Add more conditions here - if year is an integer in 1990..2100 range etc.
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxName.Text))
    return textBoxName;
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxCardNum.Text) && 
      string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxStartMonth.Text))
    return textBoxCardNum;  
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxStartYear.Text))
    return textBoxStartYear; 
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxEndmonth.Text))
    return textBoxEndmonth; 
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxEndYear.Text))
    return textBoxEndYear; 
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxNameOnCard.Text))
    return textBoxNameOnCard; 
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxCVC.Text))
    return textBoxCVC;

  return null;
}
```

Then we can save if and only if all controls are valid:

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Control failed = InvalidControl();

  if (failed != null) {  // we have an invalid control
    if (failed.CanFocus) // let user know which is it:
      failed.Focus();    // we can set keyboard focus on it

    // Let user have a message on what's going on
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid value", //TODO: put a better text here 
                     Application.ProductName, 
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                     MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
  }
  else // Validation is OK, we can close the dialog with "OK" result 
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; 
}
```

If you want enable / disable the `buttonSave` you can implement `TextChanged` event handler for *all* the controls of interest:
`textBoxName`, `textBoxCardNum`, ..., `textBoxCVC` and there

```
private void Textboxes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // we can save if and only if we have no invalid control(s)
  buttonSave.Enabled = InvalidControl() == null; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much more efficient way when checking all the textboxes than using messy comparison operator

```
List<TextBox> txts = panelName.Controls.OfType<TextBox>(); //just change the 'panelName' whether all your textboxes are located inside a form or just a panel.
foreach(TextBox txt in txts)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text)
        buttonSave.Enabled = false;
    else
        buttonSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: More efficient in what way? Why comparison operators are "messy"? Apart from that, doesn't work if the TextBoxes are not in the same container and has logical issues. With your loop the last wins.

Comment: How is this code an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to wire up (subscribe) all the text boxes `TextChanged` event to the same event. Then when the text changes in one of the text boxes, the event will fire. In the event, you could check each text box to see if they all have some text, and if they do, then enable the save button, otherwise, disable the save button.

Example, to wire up four (4) text boxes to the same `TextChanged` event may look something like…

```
textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
textBox2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
textBox3.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
textBox4.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
```

Then to help, a `List<TextBox>` may come in handy to loop though only the text boxes we want. When the form loads, the code can add the text boxes to this list, something like…

```
TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
TextBoxes.Add(textBox1);
TextBoxes.Add(textBox2);
TextBoxes.Add(textBox3);
TextBoxes.Add(textBox4);
```

Then finally, do all the comparisons in the `tetxBox_TextChanged` event. This may look something like…

```
List<TextBox> TextBoxes;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  btnSave.Enabled = false;
  textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
  textBox2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
  textBox3.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
  textBox4.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);

  TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
  TextBoxes.Add(textBox1);
  TextBoxes.Add(textBox2);
  TextBoxes.Add(textBox3);
  TextBoxes.Add(textBox4);
}


private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  foreach (TextBox tb in TextBoxes) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)) {
      btnSave.Enabled = false;
      return;
    }
  }
  btnSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

With this approach the save button will get enable when all the text boxes have some text and will be disabled is any text box is empty.